# Is the official UK website for transit visa requirements safe to follow?

Tags: visas, uk, transit, british-airways, dutch-residents

I have an Indian passport and a European residence permit card. I was travelling from Amsterdam to Abu Dhabi with a 2 hours transit time in London Heathrow without any change of airport. I was however denied boarding at Amsterdam for lack of UK transit visa. According to the UK website, it says I am exempt from a transit visa requirement due to the EEA residence permit. Did this happen to anyone else? Why was I denied boarding?

Comment: As far as I can see, you don't need a transit visa and you should have been allowed to board. We don't know why you were denied boarding: my guess would be that it was a mistake but I'm not an expert. You should probably edit your question to ask, instead, what your rights are in this situation (e.g., if you're entitled to a refund, compensation, etc.).

Comment: Did you show your EU residence card? The airline check-in agent would not know you have one otherwise.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thank you :) I have a friend with the same documents as me who has booked on the same journey and the question was to know if she should apply for a transit visa.

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes and I was still asked to cancel and rebook a new flight that does not have a transit via London!

Comment: Yes, it sounds like the airline made a serious mistake. You should not have been denied boarding. I don't know what compensation you might be owed, but you definitely should pursue that.

Comment: @Anu For completeness, which EEA country issued your residence permit? And which airline(s) were you booked with? It should not matter but it may help answers to know this.

Comment: @Traveller I have a residence permit issued by Netherlands and the airlines is British Airways.

Comment: @Anu Well they should certainly know the regulations! Here is a link to their complaints process https://www.britishairways.com/en-us/information/help-and-contacts/complaints-and-claims